# Copy and paste the cell values only without formula

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the cell values only and not the formula which is calculating the value of the cell which i am coping

```
Range("V186").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("N215").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

copying cell value with formula and showing `#REF!` instead of value

Comment: `Range("N215").value = Range("V186").value`

Comment: In addition to @GSerg, if you are wanting to do this for a larger range, you could use: `Range("V186").Copy` below, `Range("N125").PasteSpecial xlValues`

Comment: Generally you should avoid using `Select` where possible. Have a read of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).